# browser optimization of splice to slice

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have the following 2 functions:

```
//destructive
const getEveryX = (arr, x, offset) => {
    const _arr = [...arr];
    let _arrArr = [];

    if (offset && offset >= arr.length) {
        _arrArr.push(_arr.splice(0, offset));
    }
    while (_arr.length > x) {
        _arrArr.push(_arr.splice(0, x));
    }
    if (_arr.length) {
        _arrArr.push(_arr);
    }
    return _arrArr
}
```

and

```
//copying
const getEveryX2 = (arr, x, offset) => {
    let _pointer = 0;
    const _arrArr = [];

    if (offset && offset >= arr.length) {
        _arrArr.push(arr.slice(0, offset));
    }
    while (arr.length >= _pointer + x) {
        _arrArr.push(arr.slice(_pointer, _pointer + x));
        _pointer += x;
    }
    if (arr.length) {
        _arrArr.push(arr.slice(_pointer, arr.length - 1));
    }
    return _arrArr;
};
```

I wrote the second function because I thougt it would be faster to copy the parts I need from the original array instead of copying the original and splicing out the beginning every time (both functions should do the same, first uses splice, second slice) - [I tested it and this doesnt seem to be the case](https://jsperf.com/split-arrays-in-to-subarrays-slice-vs-splice), they both take the same time.

My theory is that the compiler knows what I want to do in both cases and creates the same code.
I could also be completely wrong and the second version shouldnt be faster without optimizations.

Do you know what is going on here?

Comment: I can't speak as to SpiderMonkey, but it's actually possible to see how V8 optimizes the code if you run it via Node and add some compiler directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I tested it and this doesnt seem to be the case](https://jsperf.com/split-arrays-in-to-subarrays-slice-vs-splice), they both take the same time.

No, your test case is broken. JSperf doesn't run setup and teardown for each of your snippets runs, it runs a your snippets *in a loop* between setup and teardown. You are emptying the `testArr` on the first run, the rest of the iterations only measures the `while (testArr.length > 1)` condition evaluation (yielding `false`).

[I've updated the benchmark](https://jsperf.com/split-arrays-in-to-subarrays-slice-vs-splice/2), and as expected `slice` is now performing better.

Comment: welp, guess I put this in the wrong place, thank you :)